# filtering using a OneToOneFields returning empty query set

Tags: django

I have a User model with phone field as pk. The a Transaction model with recharge_number as a OneToOne field.

I can not filter data from Transaction model using the phone number even though i do a print and the number is received from the request successfully.

Below are my code:

Models.py - User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone           = models.CharField(max_length = 15, unique = True)
    first_name      = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    last_name       = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
```

Models.py - Transaction

```
class Transaction(models.Model, Main):
    recharge_number = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recharge_number')
    network = models.CharField(choices=Main.NETWORK, max_length=10)
    recharge_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
```

serializers.py - TransactionDetailSerializer

```
class TransactionDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        model = Transaction
        fields = (
            'recharge_number',
            'network',
            'recharge_amount'
             )
```

views.py - Transactions

```
class Transactions(RetrieveAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone = request.data.get('recharge_number', False)
        print(phone)
        transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(recharge_number=phone).order_by("-timestamp")
        serializer = TransactionDetailSerializer(transaction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Results gets an empty Query - <QuerySet []>. Should not be as they are lots on transaction records with the phone number

Thanks

Comment: What was the result of `print(phone)`? Does it print anything?

Answer (score 0):

as per your question you have make a phone no as a primary key but you haven't specify that as primary key in django django automatically create its primary key as autofield if you want to make phone_no as primary key you have to specify that in your model

```
phone= models.CharField(max_length = 15, unique = True,primary_key=True)
```

i think that might be a problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be on the filter line, because probably you are comparing a string received on request with a foreign key field.

You should use a filter lookup to match the proper phone field on User model (using `recharge_number__phone`):

```py
transaction = Transaction.objects.filter(recharge_number__phone=phone).order_by("-timestamp")
```

What is the value you are getting on `print(phone)`? Are you getting the value you want?

Because you maybe are getting the phone value in a wrong way. You are using a `get` method, but you are retrieving with `request.data`. Is really that you want?

How is your url mapping? Is something like this?

```py
path('<slug:recharge_number>/', views.Transactions.as_view()),
```

Because in that way you should get the parameter with kwargs:

```py
phone = self.kwargs.get('recharge_number', False)
```

Otherwise, if you are passing the phone number in query parameter (something like `yourdomain.com/transactions/?recharge_number=99999` you should get the parameter this way:

```py
self.request.query_params.get('recharge_number', False)
```